# Chunked file upload to MySQL (from PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload, insert

I would like to be able to upload files to MySQL database, even they're big.

Currently I have to obey to MySQL `max_allowed_packets` variable, which is set to 1Mb, and I cannot/don't want change it.

So I was thinking to split the file content in N chunks, then do an "INSERT INTO" for the first chunk, get its `mysql_insert_id`, and then do a loop of "UPDATE SET" in which I concatenate the remaining chunks into the BLOB field.

I don't particularly like this solutions, I think it's a bit too *dirty*. So I'm here to ask: is there is any other better way to achieve this? Maybe with some example?

Comment: Why are you storing a file in the database?  I usually store the file in my filesystem, and just save its path in my database.  That being said, you can change `max_allowed_packets` via a query: `SET SESSION max_allowed_packet=10485760;`.

Comment: Because I would not to have to worry about unique filenames, and it's easier for me to import/export my database. With 1 export I have everything I need: records and files.

So I would like to stick to the MySQL approach.

Comment: Would running `SET SESSION max_allowed_packet=10485760;` (or whatever value, in bytes) before your `INSERT INTO ...` work?

Comment: Nope. As stated in the main question, I cannot change it.

Comment: Why can't you change it?  If you're worried about changing global settings, `SET SESSION` only changes it for the current connection.  If you can't do that, then the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` method you describe seems to be the only other method (that I can think of).

Comment: **easier?** you have already faced one of many issues and still call it easier?

Comment: Because it returns me `SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value`. And of course I cannot change GLOBAL neither, just the SUPER USER can, which I'm not.